# Is there a way of making the Active Tab Border highlighted on top instead of at the bottom?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With the `tab.activeBorder` you can highlight the bottom of the active tab, but how do you highlight the top of the tab instead, like in Firefox's current design?

An example of highlighting with `tab.activeBorder`:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {    // Can customize each aspect
    "[One Dark Pro]": {               // Optional
        "tab.activeBorder": "#0A84FF" // Active Tab Highlighting
    }
},
```

Comment: Just to chime a little. Once you are in the json settings files and you have helper turned on (I forget what that setting is called), you can see a popup of all the options when you type the opening quote:
[![settings options popup with all the options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5th0.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5th0.png)
Hovering over the options also shows the description: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GIzd.png

Answer (score 160, accepted):

You can visit the [Theme Color VS Code web page](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color) to get more information on this.

> Open your user `settings.json` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)

Two lines below the `tab.activeBorder`, you will find `tab.activeBorderTop`, which does exactly what you intended.

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {       // Can customize each aspect
    "[One Dark Pro]": {                  // Optional
        "tab.activeBorderTop": "#0A84FF" // Active Tab Top Highlighting
    }
},
```

Comment: Where is this file located ?

Comment: It doesn't work  for me when it was Inside the theme section. The error was "Property is not allowed".  But  it had worked when I have moved it into section  "workbench.colorCustomizations" (outside theme section)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. With One Dark Pro it's super difficult to see the current tab

Comment: Use "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)" from the command palette to open your `settings.json` file. On my machine it was in `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`

Comment: 1. for macOS user, `cmd` + `shift` + `P` to enable your command input,
2. then either start typing `open settings` for `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` or just paste this command `workbench.action.openSettingsJson`

Comment: It works! I just needed to change the theme (from `"[One Dark Pro]"` to `"[Default Dark+]"`). Copy your theme description in `workbench.colorTheme` field in the same `settings.json` file.

Comment: See also @tbo47's answer, you don't have to add the theme name layer.

Comment: Don't use the theme name -- see tbo47's answer to apply highlighting to all themes.

Comment: This answer is perfect for anyone who knows their way around VSCode, but for anyone who just typed "how to change vscode tab color" into a search engine then @Amol's answer is much better.

Answer (score 166):

you can add this to `.vscode/settings.json`

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBorder": "#ff0000",
    "tab.unfocusedActiveBorder": "#000000"
}
```

It looks like this

[image]

Comment: adding "tab.activeBackground": "#26549e"  is also helpful for highlighting the entire tab

Comment: If you have N split panes, this only highlights one tab. Is there any way to highlight N instead?

Answer (score 65):

You can also colorize background of tab:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBackground": "#0000ff"
}
```

Comment: Something with alpha seems to work the best; `"tab.activeBackground": "#ffffff20"`

Comment: This answer is widely incomplete compared to @Amol's answer

Comment: please don't post answers to a different question here. If you want to answer a different question, do it in the right place.

Comment: There is not always the right place. I searched for background changing and got this. Kinda helpful.

Answer (score 54):

1. Go to Settings
2. Type `colorCustomizations` in the link at the top
3. Against the option "Workbench: Color Customizations" select "Edit in settings.json" as shown in the image below
   [image]
4. Now add JSON values such as

   ```
   "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
       "tab.activeBorderTop": "#12ff00",
       "tab.activeBackground": "#c41111"
   }
   ```

Comment: Best Answer! I personally like this setting: `"tab.activeBorderTop": "#11ff008c", "tab.activeBackground": "#11ff001a",  "tab.activeBorder": "#12ff00"` It kind of gives anime feel :)

Comment: "1. Go to Settings"... psst... bottom left corner, the gear icon (or "Ctrl+Comma")...

Answer (score 11):

Many people have answered before but those are answers of people who know their way around VSCode; I've always found myself googling one or more steps of the most popular answer -- such as "open the settings", or "open the command palette".

**Here is a DETAILED answer :**

1. Open VScode
2. Open the "commands palette" ( **shift+Ctrl+P** )
3. Start typing "**preference**" in the search box. The autocomplete should offer **"Preferences : Open user settings (JSON)"**.

[image]

5. Click on that choice. It opens a JSON file named **"settings.json"**
6. You need to understand the syntax of JSON files. But in essence you need to add a section named **"workbench.colorCustomizations"**, containing two entries : **"tab.activeBorderTop"** and **"tab.activeBackground"**

[image]

7. set the color value to the desired value (in the screenshot, #FF0000 means red). *activeBorderTop* is for the thin colored bar at the top of the tab while *activeBackground* is for the whole tab's color.
8. Save the file **(Ctrl+S)** you should see the changes immediately.