# How to identify the tabs for displayed code in split-screen views?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tabs, split-screen

In vscode, I can identify the tab that is active and recolor the top of its tab as described in [Is there a way of making the Active Tab Border highlighted on top instead of at the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121072/is-there-a-way-of-making-the-active-tab-border-highlighted-on-top-instead-of-at)

But if I have a split screen, there will be a non-active tab for which code is showing in the split. How do I identify and color that tab?

Basically, in split-screen mode, the recipe above was not enough to make it clear which tab's code is showing in each group of tabs.

Comment: with theme **Light+** you can clearly see which tab in which split is the active tab, if other themes don't you can customize there colors

Answer (score 1):

Look at the various `tab.unfocusedActive....` `colorCustomizations`, like

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

   "tab.unfocusedActiveBorderTop": "#ff0000",

}
```

which will give the "active" editor in an unfocused split group a red border top.